# JMeter "Parameters" variable not convertable to Integer

Tags: jmeter

I can't get my `${invoiceTotalCsv}` parameter to respond to math equations. I am taking it from from a CSV file in which it is a number, usually with a decimal place.

The below code works, but if `${invoiceTotalCsv} = 10`, then the log writes `101`, not 11. This leads me to believe the variable is passed as a string. BUT, I've tried Parameters.toInteger() which throws a `NumberFormatException`.

No other clues are given by JMeter.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert String to number/int, in groovy script:

```
 def total = Parameters as double
```

Comment: That does not work unfortunately. All I get is:

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "350998.0"

Comment: "as double" worked on the other hand, and so did Parameters.toDouble(). Tought I tried that already. Oh well.

Comment: I had to make sure I log a string by adding + "" also, it doesn't compile with a double as input.

Answer (score -1):

You can use JSR223 Sampler element and then convert your Jmeter variable in int, float or double as required.

For better understanding see this [page](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/creating-jmeter-variables-in-java-the-ultimate-guide)

Comment: Your link has no information about converting or parsing. Maybe the source article has been changed?